# Firebase date-range query not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to do two separate queries from Firebase. The first is just a general query that gets the total number of entries saved. That works correctly.

The second one is supposed to be a time based range query that determines all of the entries saved for just this year.

The first query is working. The second is displaying "null" in the console. It should also display "10" as all the queries were created in 2016.

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://xxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/entries');
    ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    $scope.allEntries = snapshot.numChildren();
        console.log('Total entries saved to date: ' + $scope.allEntries);
        // shows 10 entries, which is correct
    });

var ref2 = new Firebase('https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com/');
ref2.child('entries')
    .startAt(14516244) // January 1st, 2016
    .endAt(1472131318) // current date (aug, 25th 2016)
    .once('value', function(snapshot) {
            console.log(snapshot.numChildren());
            // shows "null"
});
```

Here is a look at the timestamps from the first entry and the last entry.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing `orderByChild()` in your second query.

Add it at the beginning of the query:

```
ref2.child('entries')
    .orderByChild('createdAt')
    .startAt(14516244) // January 1st, 2016
    .endAt(1472131318) // current date (aug, 25th 2016)
    .once('value', function(snapshot) {
            console.log(snapshot.numChildren());
            // shows "null"
});
```

Edit:

Second problem is that your dates in query are too small, because they are in seconds and your *createdAt* is in miliseconds. Convert it.

```
ref2.child('entries')
    .orderByChild('createdAt')
    .startAt(14516244000) // January 1st, 2016
    .endAt(1472131318000) // current date (aug, 25th 2016)
    .once('value', function(snapshot) {
            console.log(snapshot.numChildren());
            // shows "null"
});
```

Comment: I now get "0" instead of "null". It should be "10".

Comment: I know where the problem is, I will edit the answer in a second.

Comment: The problem is that `startAt()` and `endAt()` don't accept a `long`......